# Python script continue through null

Tags: python, null

I am running into an issue finding the proper documentation for this. My script will run until it hit the null value of player as you can see below and than stops. I think there needs to be a `if statement` in the `Player` `for loop` I am just struggling with the proper way to write it and finding exactly what i am looking for.

```
    import base64
    import requests
    import json
    import csv

    USERNAME, PASSWORD = 'Name', 'Pass'

    header = ["Update", "Home_Abbrev", "Home_Pos", "Home_First", "Home_Last", "Away_Abbrev", "Away_Pos", "Away_First", "Away_Last"]
    headers = {
            "Authorization": "Basic " +
                    base64.b64encode('{}:{}'.format(USERNAME,PASSWORD)\
                                    .encode('utf-8')).decode('ascii')
        }

    with open("GameDayLines.csv", 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow(header)
        for gameid in range(41262,41264):  #ENTER GAME ID'S 12/14/2017
            req = requests.get(url="https://api.mysportsfeeds.com/v1.1/pull/nhl/2017-2018-regular/game_startinglineup.json?gameid=" + str(gameid) , headers=headers)
            req.raise_for_status()
            data = req.json()

            starting_lineup = data['gamestartinglineup']
            update = starting_lineup['lastUpdatedOn']

            away_team_abbrev = starting_lineup['game']['awayTeam']
            home_team_abbrev = starting_lineup['game']['homeTeam']
            away_abbrev = away_team_abbrev['Abbreviation']
            home_abbrev = home_team_abbrev['Abbreviation']

            team_away = starting_lineup['teamLineup'][0]['expected']['starter']
            team_home = starting_lineup['teamLineup'][1]['expected']['starter']

            for i in range(20):
                home_player_first = team_home[i]['player']['FirstName']
                home_player_last = team_home[i]['player']['LastName']
                home_player_pos = team_home[i]['position']

                away_player_first = team_away[i]['player']['FirstName']
                away_player_last = team_away[i]['player']['LastName']
                away_player_pos = team_away[i]['position']                

                writer.writerow([update, home_abbrev, home_player_pos, home_player_first, home_player_last, away_abbrev, away_player_pos, away_player_first, away_player_last])
                print(update, home_abbrev, home_player_pos, home_player_first, home_player_last, away_abbrev, away_player_pos, away_player_first, away_player_last)
```

Here is what the json looks like:

```
    1   
    position    "ForwardLine1-RW"
    player  
    ID  "5605"
    LastName    "Rantanen"
    FirstName   "Mikko"
    JerseyNumber    "96"
    Position    "RW"
    2   
    position    "ForwardLine2-C"
    player  
    ID  "5564"
    LastName    "Compher"
    FirstName   "J.T."
    JerseyNumber    "37"
    Position    "LW"
    3   
    position    "ForwardLine4-C"
    player  null
```

Comment: look into `try/except` blocks to catch errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If home_player and away_player can be null you should check them just before usage like

```
for i in range(20): 
    if team_home[i]['player'] is not None:
        home_home_player_firstplayer_first = team_home[i]['player']['FirstName'] 
        home_player_last = team_home[i]['player']['LastName'] 
        home_player_pos = team_home[i]['position'] 

    if team_away[i]['player'] is not None:
        away_player_first = team_away[i]['player']['FirstName'] 
        away_player_last = team_away[i]['player']['LastName'] 
        away_player_pos = team_away[i]['position']
```

Comment: In python `null` is `None`. Also this will raise a `NameError` in the next lines if a player doesn't exist.

Comment: thanks for the correction, it is just early in the morning. And yes there have to be another check before the writer

Comment: No problem, it happens if you switch between languages too often. I forget semicolons and parentheses all the time..

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, thats exactly what i was trying, just not in the right manner.